# Randomly print a dictionary key, then compare its value with another dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, dictionary

I have a problem with printing a random key from a dictionary. With the random of dict_2 everything works correctly, and the function also works correctly, but with the random of `dict_1` there is something wrong.

The purpose of this code is to randomly select the key of `dict_1` and `dict_2`, **"compare"** them grammatically using the function (the keys of dict_1 and dict_2 must have the same gender and unit) and then print them. The function works correctly

**IMPORTANT:** I ​​cannot use the same code I used for `dict_2`, because otherwise I will get a key WITHOUT its values, so it cannot be "compared" to `dict_2` using the get_example function. Even using `list(dict_1.items())` and not `list(dict_1.keys())`, I can't compare values ​​with the other dictionary. Instead, currently, the values ​​are compared correctly, but there is no randomization of `dict_1`. I am making several attempts, but I get so many different errors, too many different errors.

How can I randomly get a `dict_1` key? I always print only the "archiviato" or "archiviata" key of `dict_1`, but I would like to print a random one among all those of dict_1. I know the solution is very simple, but I can't. All the rest of the code works fine. Who can help me?

I have split the dictionary and code for cleanliness and clarity, but below is the complete code.

This is my small code:

```
import random

#Random Dict_2
x = list(dict_2.keys()) 
x_random = random.choice(x)

#Relate the grammar of the two dictionaries to find the correct word
def get_example(x_random):
    for key, value in dict_1.items():
        if dict_2[x_random] == value:
            return key

function = get_example(x_random)

test = f"{function} {x_random}"
print(test)
```

This is dictionary:

```
dict_1 = {

            #Male
            "archiviato " : {
            "genere" : "maschile",
            "unità" : "singolare",
            },

            "gestito " : {
            "genere" : "maschile",
            "unità" : "singolare",
            },
                      
            "smarrito " : {
            "genere" : "maschile",
            "unità" : "singolare",
            },

            #Female
            "archiviata " : {
            "genere" : "femminile",
            "unità" : "singolare",
            },
      
            "gestita " : {
            "genere" : "femminile",
            "unità" : "singolare",
            },
             
            "smarrita " : {
            "genere" : "femminile",
            "unità" : "singolare",
            },      
        }
    
dict_2 = {

            #Male
            "il documento" : {
            "genere" : "maschile",
            "unità" : "singolare",
            },

            "il foglio" : {
            "genere" : "maschile",
            "unità" : "singolare",
            },

            "lo scatolone" : {
            "genere" : "maschile",
            "unità" : "singolare",
            },


            #Female        
            "la cartella" : {
            "genere" : "femminile",
            "unità" : "singolare",
            },
                      
            "la borsa" : {
            "genere" : "femminile",
            "unità" : "singolare",
            },

            "la chiave" : {
            "genere" : "femminile",
            "unità" : "singolare",
            },
                      
        }
```

This is code complete:

```
import random

dict_1 = {

            #Maschili
            "archiviato " : {
            "genere" : "maschile",
            "unità" : "singolare",
            },

            "gestito " : {
            "genere" : "maschile",
            "unità" : "singolare",
            },
                      
            "smarrito " : {
            "genere" : "maschile",
            "unità" : "singolare",
            },

                  
        
            #Femmili
            "archiviata " : {
            "genere" : "femminile",
            "unità" : "singolare",
            },
      
            "gestita " : {
            "genere" : "femminile",
            "unità" : "singolare",
            },
             
            "smarrita " : {
            "genere" : "femminile",
            "unità" : "singolare",
            },      
        }



dict_2 = {

            #Maschili
            "il documento" : {
            "genere" : "maschile",
            "unità" : "singolare",
            },

            "il foglio" : {
            "genere" : "maschile",
            "unità" : "singolare",
            },

            "lo scatolone" : {
            "genere" : "maschile",
            "unità" : "singolare",
            },


            #Femminili        
            "la cartella" : {
            "genere" : "femminile",
            "unità" : "singolare",
            },
                      
            "la borsa" : {
            "genere" : "femminile",
            "unità" : "singolare",
            },

            "la chiave" : {
            "genere" : "femminile",
            "unità" : "singolare",
            },
                      
        }


#Random Dict_2
x = list(dict_2.keys()) 
x_random = random.choice(x)

#Relate the grammar of the two dictionaries to find the correct word
def get_example(x_random):
    for key, value in dict_1.items():
        if dict_2[x_random] == value:
            return key

function = get_example(x_random)

test = f"{function} {x_random}"
print(test)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than returning as soon as you find a match, I would suggest keeping track of all matches, then picking one of the matches at random.

Example:

```
import random

#Random Dict_2
x = list(dict_2.keys()) 
x_random = random.choice(x)

#Relate the grammar of the two dictionaries to find the correct word
def get_example(x_random):
    matches = []
    for key, value in dict_1.items():
        if dict_2[x_random] == value:
            matches.append(key)
    # If matches has no elements here, this will cause an error
    return random.choice(matches)

function = get_example(x_random)

test = f"{function} {x_random}"
print(test)
```

Comment: What do you mean by matches? What are matches? I did not understand the translation of the word. Can you explain yourself better? (I'm starting out with Python). Thank you

Comment: @Max Sorry, I will explain. Matches, (or a match) are something which is equal. So "archiviato" matches "il documento." When you say `"compare" them grammatically using the function (the keys of dict_1 and dict_2 must have the same gender and unit) and then print them.` something which is the same is a match. There are other meanings of match, but this is the meaning I am using.

Comment: Ah okok, sorry, I had misinterpreted the translation of the word. So in the code you suggested (if I understand correctly), your idea is to add inside matches = [] all the keys of dict_1 (after correct grammar comparison)? Next, use a random key of matches? It's right?

Comment: Yes, but matches is a list, and lists don't have keys. They just have values. So I am getting a random value of matches.